# Mysql binlog path from mysql console

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

Is there a way to know the bin log files path from mysql console as we can know whether its ON or OFF by using

```
Select * information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES
where variable_name like '%log_bin%'.
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this to show **on/off**:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin'
```

**Also:**

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%bin%'
```

Or

```
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE ...
```

**More Information: (notice that some of these values and results changed from 5.5 to 5.6!)**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-master-status.html

```
mysql > SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.003 | 73       | test         | manual,mysql     |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+

mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
+---------------+-----------+
| Log_name      | File_size |
+---------------+-----------+
| binlog.000015 |    724935 |
| binlog.000016 |    733481 |
+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: No,Iam asking is there a way to know where the binlog.0000xx is present from console instead of my.cnf like `mysql> SELECT * from information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES where variable_name like 'slow_query%';
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME       | VARIABLE_VALUE                       |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| SLOW_QUERY_LOG      | ON                                   | 
| SLOW_QUERY_LOG_FILE | /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql_slow.log | 
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
`

Comment: It does not look like there is an absolute path. But you can parse mysql config with PHP or bash, or just hardcode to `/var/log` or something

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) regarding `log-bin`"

```
Setting this option causes the log_bin system variable to be set 
to ON (or 1), and not to the base name. This is a known issue; 
see Bug #19614 for more information.
```

There is a workaround using `mysqld` instead in the [Bug 19614](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19614) which I modified a bit. If you are scripting, you can use from the `mysql` client (which I found a bit tedious to do, see the next workaround):

`mysql >\! dirname $(mysqld --help --verbose 2> /dev/null | egrep "^log-bin " | grep -o "\/.*")`

Looks like there is a patch submitted by Mark Callaghan, and it was never committed. There is a function in [WP5465](http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=5465) (which is the work in progress for this patch), however it didn't work properly for me, as the location of the logs can be different across setups.